# Lightworks detects aspect ratio incorrectly and clips video from ShadowPlay

Tags: video-editor, mp4, aspect

I'm using Nvidia's ShadowPlay to record some game footage, and I am trying to edit it in Lightworks. When I import it, it clips off the edges of the content. I have the project set at 1080p 30fps (I presume 16:9), exporting at 720p 30fps Youtube/MP4, and am importing 1366x768 (16:9?) footage. I'm using Lightworks 12.0.1 on 32bit Windows 7 (2/3GB ram but rest is restricted by 32bit). The variable framerate seems to play ok, I just set it to run at 60/30fps instead of 59.9/29.9fps. It exports fine but the edges are clipped. I tried to change the aspect ratio on one of the other clips using the filecard, but I can't get to it now, as the filecard in the bin says that it is 1366x768 PC display, and when I try to get the filecard up in the edit (e.g. right-clicking on the track), nothing happens.

You can see how it's clipped off here, and it's the same in the export:
[image: FIFA 13 clipped footage]

You can see it in the player name tag at the right of the footage.
My recordings are at several different framerates, the first at 30fps and the last two at 60fps, but I think Lightworks makes them run at 30fps.

Is there any way I could get it to work? Do I need to transcode it in Handbrake or something? If not, I'll just have to use Windows Movie Maker...

Comment: I managed to get Shotcut to work, it has all the features I need and took me several hours less to get started with. I don't seem to have any aspect ratio problems with Shotcut, exporting at 16:9... however at 1366x768 - I'll let youtube deal with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No clue about Lightworks, but two possible (and possibly related) issues are that 1366x768 is not exactly 16:9, and 1366 is not evenly divisible by 8. Either or both could cause any editing software to use a different internal representation, and require an adjustment to its display.

1368x768 would be byte-aligned, but still not 16:9.

Comment: Strange... see my comment on my question for my status, this may still help other people though